# Extention method not working when trying to add method to the Blazor's IJSRuntime service

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I injected the IJSRuntime service into my code, and I'm trying to create an extension method to reduce the mess of having to use `await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "my message")`  to simply the created method, which wold be something like `await js.ConfirmMethod("my message")`

However, after creating the extension method, it states: "'IJSRuntime' does not contain a definition for 'confirMethod' and no accessible extension method 'confirMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'IJSRuntime' could be found"

The main component

```
@inject IJSRuntime js

@code
{
    public int one = 1;
    [Parameter] public List<Books> ?Library {get; set;}
    public async Task deleteBook(Books book)
    {
        var confirm = await js.confirMethod($"Are you sure you want to delete {book.bookName}?");

        @if(confirm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The book {book.bookName} by {book.author} has been deleted");
            Library.Remove(book);
        }
    }
}
```

The extension method class

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace blazorTestApp.Client.Classes_FE
{
    public static class IJSExtentionMethods
    {

        public static async ValueTask<bool> confirMethod(this IJSRuntime js, string message)
        {

            bool confirm = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", message);
            return confirm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The razor component can not find the extension method, because the namespace is not imported anywhere.

There are a few ways you can solve this and you should choose whichever is appropriate for you.

1. You can add `blazorTestApp.Client.Classes_FE` namespace to the `Imports.razor`
2. You can change the namespace of your extension method to `Microsoft.JSInterop` this is sometimes done for discoverability reasons
3. You can add `@using blazorTestApp.Client.Classes_FE` to the top of your razor component to import the namespace

Comment: I have added it actually, I tried adding it to the import file and I also tried adding it directly to the namespace using @using blazorTestApp.Client.Classes_FE, but neither worked

Comment: ok, I tried changing the namespace to Microsoft.JSInterop and that worked. But could you explain to me why the other options did not work?

Comment: @Saucter Unfortunately I can't because when I tried it locally, it simply worked. But judging from the fact that changing it to the namespace `Microsoft.JSInterop` works, it means that somehow it is not possible to find the `blazorTestApp.Client.Classes_FE` namespace. Hope that helps you somehow.

Comment: [Polite] This is not a good answer.  Why? You should not "invade" other people's namespaces, and an answer on here should not promote doing so.  Find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I kindly disagree with you, because I gave 3 different options to solve the issue, you seem to think that one of the options I gave "using an externals type namespace" is bad practice, but that is just your opinion. If you look at popular libraries e.g. Automapper they are using the same approach [see here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

Comment: @SelmirAljic - ;-)  I specifically didn't say "bad practice": there are always valid reasons to break conventions.  However here, putting stuff into the Microsoft namespace just masks a local namespace problem that the OP ought to fix.   You don't need to do it: it doesn't fell right; treating the symptoms, not the cause..

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I agree, choosing option 2 over the other options simply because it works is not a good reason to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's your provided code in a standalone reproducible project.

It works, so your problem is in your namespacing.  first declare the namespace where you're using the extension and then fix your usings and imports files.

A class to define your extension method:

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace SO75433586.Data;

public static class IJSExtentionMethods
{
    public static async ValueTask<bool> confirMethod(this IJSRuntime js, string message)
    {
        bool confirm = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", message);
        return confirm;
    }
}
```

And it being used in a page:

```
@page "/"
@namespace SO75433586.Data
@inject IJSRuntime js

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=Confirm> Confirm</button>

@code {
    public async Task Confirm()
    {
        var confirm = await js.confirMethod($"Are you sure you want to delete?");
    }
}
```